# JSON parse single string to object

Tags: java, json, gson

is there any easy way to to convert this json:

```
{
    ...,
    "pictures": [
        "url1",
        "url2"
    ],
    ...
}
```

to

```
List<Picture> pictures
```

where Picture is:

```
class Picture{
      String url;
}
```

It won't work as above, because I have an exception, saying

```
Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING
```

Comment: A quick fix depending on your use of the object could be to put `@JsonValue` above the getter for your `String url`.

Comment: @Zircon Wrong library. Also, that would only be useful for serializing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement a custom deserializer for this.
Should be looking like this (I didn't try to execute, but that should give you the idea where to start, presumably you have a public constructor with `String` argument in your `Picture.class`)

```
private class PictureDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Picture> {
  public Picture deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context)
      throws JsonParseException {
    return new Picture(json.getAsJsonPrimitive().getAsString());
  }
}
```

It should be registered:

```
GsonBuilder gson = new GsonBuilder();
gson.registerTypeAdapter(Picture.class, new PictureDeserializer());
```

Comment: I know deserializer method to do this thing, is there any other way to avoid making deserializer?

Comment: @PaleNisko Then you should mention it in the question to avoid making people to waist time. Anyway, the answer: I don't think so. The mapper contains a predefined set of actions mapped to the most generic types/classes on one-to-one relationship basis (simplified). Going through JSON tree, the mapper encounters different types/classes and deserializes them accordingly. E.g. single string is mapped to the String.class out-of-box. If you have a custom Picture.class, the mapper just cannot have the consistent mapping out-of-box as its developers couldn't keep in mind all classes in the world.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your feedback i will keep in mind your advice. Know I understand why it is done like that!